# Cant load PHP files on MAMP localhost

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, mamp

I have a project folder that I've been working on with with WAMP on Windows, but I moved everything over to MAMP on the Mac. I've got the project file uploaded to a webspace and everything works fine, so I know the code is fine. I've imported all the MYSQL data from WAMP.

I can access the `.html` files with no problems on the Mac but when I try to run a `.php` file I receive the message `localhost is currently unable to handle this request.` and the error code `500`.

I've been searching for hours and can't find a fix for this.

Any ideas as to why I am seeing these messages and cant access any `.php` files?

Some extra info on the mamp setup:

- Apache port: `8888`
- MYSQL port: `8889`

Comment: This is an old post that I'm coming back to, I find it a common occurrence for things like this to happen on StackOverflow, where I see well presented questions marked as unclear. I thought this was a clear question, I clearly said that I couldn't access .php files and showed the error message; and I asked for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is making sure that you hit the correct folder. The easiest way is probably by adding a `test.php` file in your project public root and putting something like `<?php echo "hello world";` in there. And then you just browse to `localhost:8888/my-project/test.php` and check if the world gets greeted.

The second thing I would do is check the error logs. "localhost is currently unable to handle this request." is not very helpful for debugging. You should be able to find `apache_error.log` and `php_error.log` inside `/Applications/MAMP/logs`

Feel free to ask if that didn't help locating the issue, or if you are still stuck...

Comment: thank you, first created the test.php and seen that it was working. So I followed your second piece of advice. I had to change the version of PHP I was using, based on the log information.

Comment: It wasnt exact, but when I read it a lightbulb went off. It was the only thing I hadnt tried. At first I was getting the .php files to load but there was no database communication. So I just changed the version of PHP I would be using and it solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working again. I can imagine the frustration, we've all been there. Happy coding!